# antd protable unable to change language to english

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

Hi I am using antd protable to display data and even though i have defined the default language as English for some of the parts it is still showing Chinese

```
import ProTable, { IntlProvider, enUSIntl } from '@ant-design/pro-table';

  <IntlProvider value={enUSIntl}>
    <ProTable
     scroll={{ x: 1300 }}
     options={{ fullScreen: false, reload: true, setting: true }}
     request={allCustomers}
     columns={columns}
     />
   </IntlProvider>
```

Everything else is changes to English except the pagination information.

Please help

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved the issue by updating antd protable version to 2.3.1

edit

If you are not still not able to resolve it by updating antd protable version to 2.3.1, Try this

```
 <ProTable
...otherProps
 pagination={{
  showTotal: (total, range) => (
  <div>{`Showing ${range[0]}-${range[1]} of ${total} total items`}</div>     
     ),
       }}
/>
```

Comment: hey thanks for this, i was able to change the pagination language, is there any way to do the same for that small popup we get for hiding/showing table columns?